# Enable/Disable an Edit Text depending on selected spinner Item

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spinner

I have a spinner containing most of the possible Skills of a person and an "Others" selectable item. I also have an "Other Skills" EditText that I want to be disabled on default but be enabled once the user selects "Others" from the Spinner. This is what I tried but it won't even show the Toast message.

I have the focusable of the EditText set to false in the XML file

```
            android:id="@+id/otherSkill"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:backgroundTint="#E7E4E4"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Other Skill"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:focusable="false"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/skills" />
```

Java Code

```
skills.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                if (text=="Others"){
                    Toast.makeText(UserSignup.this, "aa " + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    otherSkill.setFocusable(true);
                } else {
                    otherSkill.setFocusable(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

But if i try to show the Toast message of "text" before the IF ELSE statement it displays "Others".

```
               String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(JobSeekerSignup.this, "aa " + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
otherSkill.setEnabled(true)
```

then this

```
otherSkill.setEnabled(false)
```